# PHP Image don't upload

Tags: php, upload

I am dont' uploading image file to my path. I added **enctype='multipart/form-data'** in html code. That's php code;

```
$membeUrl = "inc/img/user/".$_SESSION['memberName'];

if(!is_dir($membeUrl)){mkdir($membeUrl);}
$profilePhoto = $membeUrl."/".$_FILES['profilePhoto']['name'];

if($_FILES['profilePhoto']['error'] > 0){
    alert("Profil photo error:".$_FILES['profilePhoto']['error']);
}

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profilePhoto']['tmp_name'],$profilePhoto);

$w = " WHERE email='a@a.com' AND age='18'";

if((!preg_match("/[\-]{2,}|[;]|[']|[\\\*]/",$profilePhoto))){
    mysql_query("UPDATE member SET pp='".$profilePhoto."'".$w);
}
```

I don't see and understand. How we do solve?

Thank you for your insterest.
Good works..

Comment: what's the output of
$_FILES['profilePhoto']['tmp_name'];
$profilePhoto

Comment: "alert(...)" is a javascript function not PHP

Comment: @Sudhir How do you know? Maybe it has a php function definition in the source...

Comment: @hallaji well, its a guess, as the question does not mention anything about if "alert(..)" is a custom function done in PHP... !

Comment: what part exactly doesn't work? `move_uploaded_files()` or `mysql_query()`? What you get displayed with `var_dump($_FILES);`? Does the folder in which you move image exist and is writable? Are you using win or linux (unix-like)?

Comment: I have identified "alert" to view errors.

$_FILES['profilePhoto']['tmp_name'] is empty..
$profilePhoto is inc/img/member/fthmad9/DSC_0013.jpg

I am using xampp on the windows 8.

var_dump;
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "DSC_0013.jpg" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(1) ["size"]=> int(0) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `var_dump()` info you specified it is obvious file you are uploading exceeds `php.ini`  `upload_max_filesize` directive (check the Error=1 code explanation in [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php))

Either upload a smaller file or change `php.ini` value.

Also check that `post_max_size` ini directive is equal or larger than `upload_max_filesize`, since even if you put larger size for upload, post value is the absolute limit.
To know more about ini directives read manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize